# Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, samsung

Is it safe to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Samsung NC-110 netbook from a liveUSB, or does it have UEFI problems? I'd like to install Ubuntu alongside my current Windows 7 OS, but I googled "problems dual booting Ubuntu" and 'Samsung UEFI' appeared a lot. I don't really want to brick my computer, and so was wondering whether it would be safe to dual boot or not? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Dual boot is not a problem if UEFI is not a problem. 
To check if UEFI is a problem, you can try liveUSB without installation first, if it can boot into liveUSB, probably with some configuration in BIOS to disable security boot and enable Legacy mode, it can install on your hard disk. I don't think you can brick your computer, UEFI will try to stop you from booting into non-windows OS, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks. I've bought an external HDD, and so have installed Ubuntu onto that (which is slower, but shouldn't run any risk of bricking) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dual boot your system with Windows and Ubuntu, I suggest using WUBI an installer program which runs on Windows. Using this you can install and uninstall Ubuntu like any other program check complete guide on how to do it

http://www.aquicklookat.com/linux/installing-ubuntu-within-windows/

Comment: **wubi is deprecated...**  Follow the **[Official instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)** instead!